# How to run background process to check if user session is End

Tags: android, session, gson, retrofit

i was try to create login session with session key, the session key always generate new key either we do Login/registration, i can retrieve the data from my gson

```
LoginService loginService = retrofit.create(LoginService.class);
            Observable<LoginResponse> obs = loginService.logins(emai,pass,"1", Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID), Build.MODEL, Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
            obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                    subscribe(new Observer<LoginResponse>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }

                        public void onNext(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
                            int responses = loginResponse.getCODE();
                            String texts="";
                            if(responses == 1)
                            {
                                User user = loginResponse.getDATALIST().get(0);
                                setPrefIsLogin(true);
                                setPrefSessionUid(user.getSESSIONKEY(),user.getUSERID());
                                nextActivity();
                            }
                            else{
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

the question is, how to make handler to handle the save session check if there is another login activity with the same account?

Comment: On your mobile or or on another device?

Comment: @aa_oo on another mobile, to prevent multiple login

Comment: You should do it from server end. If you find out your accessToken (or user has asked for accessToken, during login from another device), you will just won't allow this user to log in. It's not possible do from your device end to check for multiple login feature.

Comment: in the case, if i try to dual login, the old one should auto logout, can i just check the session/accessToken, if different then the old one logged out? or there is another way to handle that more effectively? @aa_oo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never assign two accessToken/Session for one user. You will send the same accessToken to the other instance of the new user. Plus side, user won't be able to duplicate his/her work by two accessToken.

If you want to force the other/first one AUTO-LOGOUT, you can use Firebase notification feature to send a notification to that particular deviceID and force it to stop. You can check firebase's tutorial to see how they work. 
Another slow procedure is to check before login & everyother server side work to check if there are instance of same user. You will send an error and user end will receive it and show the error accompanying by logging out the user.

Comment: @AldiRenaldiGunawan, anytime mate